# Open a new window and tile the resulting windows

Tags: javascript, window

I would like use `window.open()` to open a new tab/window. Then I would like the existing window and the new one to display on either side of the screen. So that I can compare both webpages next to each other. What would happen if you used Windows Key + Left Arrow on one window and Windows Key + Right Arrow on the other.

Is this possible using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

The following code works **if you have the the pop-up blocker disabled or add the domain to it's exceptions** (otherwise it is going to open a single window and block the second one).

It creates a `height=500,width=400` window and places it at `left=100,top=100` of the screen. Then, places the second window at `left=500,top=100`(*where 500 is the previous window position + the previous window width*).

HTML

```
<input type="button" value="click" onclick="popups()">
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function popups() {    
window.open('http://www.example.com/','popUpWindow','height=500,width=400,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes');      
window.open('http://www.example.com/','popUpWindow','height=500,width=400,left=500,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes');    
}
```

[**Codepen DEMO**](http://codepen.io/freestock/pen/KzoRJL?editors=1010)

> Reference: [Quack it tutorials](http://www.quackit.com/javascript/popup_windows.cfm)